# why are ∀x(P(x)→ ∃y(Q(y)∧R(x,y))) and ∃y(Q(y)∧∀x(P(x)→(R(x,y))) not logically equivalent?

Tags: logic, proof

been sitting here for hours and still can't figure this out. 
is the order of ∀x and ∃y important in this case?

all I can think of now is "all P is R of some Q", but I don't think this is right.

Comment: Already [asked and answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3450071/why-are-forall-xpx-rightarrow-exists-yqy%e2%88%a7rx-y-text-and-exists-y) in MSE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because has been already asked and answered in MSE.